# What could be causing assoc to say "the system cannot find the file specified"?

Tags: windows-7, windows, cmd.exe, file-association

I am running assoc from an administrative command prompt

I'd like to add an entry for .vbsc in my list of associations.  It won't let me, Though it will let me do one for .vbsd    And it is running assoc.  (if it wasn't finding assoc it'd say it's not recognized).  So what's going on?

I do have a program(a wrapper for cscript.exe) that I wrote that I have linked to .vbsc files, it does attach, though as you see from the grep, it doesn't get listed listed in assoc for some reason, which is an oddity, but the oddity i'm asking about here(which may be related), is why does `assoc .vbsc=` on my machine say "The system cannot find the file specified"?

```
C:\>assoc .vbsc=  <--- fails, i'd expect it to work
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\>assoc .abc=  <-- works, no error

C:\>assoc .abcd= <-- works, no error

C:\>assoc .vbsd=  <-- works, no error

C:\>
```

and for a reminder of what it shown when a command isn't recognized.

```
C:\>hjghjgjhgjh
'hjghjgjhgjh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>
```

and more info

```
C:\>assoc | grep -i vbs
.vbs=VBSFile

C:\>ftype | grep -i vbs
VBSFile=C:\blah\mycscriptwrapper.exe %1
VBS_Cscr=C:\blah\mycscriptwrapper.exe %1

C:\>
```

**added clarification**

and if anybody finds the above rather hard to understand with the arrows and descriptions, and prefers no english and just a screenshot, here is a link to such a screenshot, it shows just the main part of what is above.

[image]

and it gets stranger.

[image]

Jozef has suggested something which I think might essentially be the breakthrough. Doing `reg query hkcr\.vbsc` and with /s.  Comparing that with .abc  shows differences.

**UPDATE**
I will merge this into jozef's answer.. but here temporarily as a record.

```
    C:\Users\harvey>reg query hkcr\.vbsc

    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vbsc\OpenWithList
    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vbsc\PersistentHandler
    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vbsc\Shell

    C:\Users\harvey>reg query hkcr\.vbsc  /s

    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vbsc\OpenWithList

    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vbsc\PersistentHandler
        OriginalPersistentHandler    REG_SZ    {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
    }

    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vbsc\Shell

    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vbsc\Shell\Open

    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vbsc\Shell\Open\Command
        (Default)    REG_EXPAND_SZ    VBS_Cscr


    C:\Users\harvey>
```

with .abc, even with

assoc abc=RAZ

(and even with ftype set it's still only this for .abc )

```
C:\Users\harvey>reg query hkcr\.abc

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.abc
    (Default)    REG_SZ    RAZ


C:\Users\harvey>

with ftype set you also get this key 

ftype RAZ=c:\blah\blah.exe

C:\Users\harvey>reg query hkcr\RAZ /s

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\RAZ\Shell

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\RAZ\Shell\Open

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\RAZ\Shell\Open\Command
    (Default)    REG_EXPAND_SZ    c:\blah\blah.exe


C:\Users\harvey>

C:\Users\harvey>reg delete hkcr\.vbsc
Permanently delete the registry key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vbsc (Yes/No)? y
The operation completed successfully.
```

and now it works.. no idea how those other entries got there..  possibly a mix of  'default programs editor' and start.."change the file type associated with a specific extension" and making a .vbsc icon and choosing a program with open with, and assoc.

[image]

Comment: `'assocc'`  is not recognized but `assoc` works… See typo in the first assoc**c** (note doubled **c**)

Comment: @JosefZ I would downvote your comment if I could. You have not understood my question or the reason why I wrote that example of 'assocc' with the typo, and you are wrong to say that assoc is working(see the first line and you see assoc giving a strange error). My point was to show what error message you get if you type a command that doesn't exist.  I will change that example though to make it clearer. And assoc is clearly not working right, see the very first line where I executed assoc and got that error.

Comment: Sorry if you think that anybody merits punishment for misunderstanding wrongly formulated question.  Your question _keeps_ wrongly formulated: `assoc .vbsc=  <---` **works** and says that cannot find the file `"---"`, see documentation for `<` _Less-Than Sign_ explanation. For proof, run it again after `echo(>---` or another `---` file creating procedure. `assoc .vbsc` with no additional trailing characters should give right result. In case of `File association not found for extension .vbsc` message try `reg query hkcu\Software\Classes\.vbsc  /S` as `assoc` does not test `HKCU` but only `HKCR`

Comment: BTW, `assoc .ext=` will *delete the association* for that `.ext` file extension if run **elevated** but otherwise would raise `Errorlevel` 5 with `Access is denied` message.

Comment: @JosefZ  You misunderstand again, you don't realize that `<-----` is an ARROW draw in ascii.  It's not a command.  And the output as you should be able to see, says nothing about any "---" file.  My question shows that I ran  `assoc .vbsc=` and got the error  but ran `assoc .abcd=` and did not get the error.  And of course nowhere did the error mention anything that you says it mentioned, just look at the error, it's there in my question.

Comment: @JosefZ furthermore, the very first line tells you that I ran this from an administrative cmd prompt. So I don't see why you are telling me about running elevated. And I know `assoc .abc=` will delete the extension(and it'll give no error either when there is no extension to delete). I said the command doesn't work for `.vbsc`. Look at the error messagel Please read carefully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39195/discussion-between-josefz-and-barlop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**added note from barlop --**  solution was the troubleshooting step of `reg query hkcr\.vbsd` and with /s will among other things, include values. This differs from hkcr.abcd  and the solution is to delete the key. Let assoc produce the key and what is necessary within that key. ----

After all explanation, I can reproduce the problem:

```
C:\Windows\system32> assoc .vbsd=

C:\Windows\system32> assoc .vbsd=abc
.vbsd=abc

C:\Windows\system32> assoc .vbsd=

C:\Windows\system32> assoc .vbsd=

C:\Windows\system32> reg add HKCR\.vbsd\AnyKeyName /f
The operation completed successfully.

C:\Windows\system32> assoc .vbsd=
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Windows\system32> reg delete HKCR\.vbsd\AnyKeyName /f
The operation completed successfully.

C:\Windows\system32> assoc .vbsd=

C:\Windows\system32> assoc .vbsd=

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Here are protocols from [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645): successful `assoc .vbsd=`

```
"Process Name","Operation","Path","Result","Detail"
"cmd.exe","RegQueryKey","HKLM","SUCCESS","Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0"
"cmd.exe","RegOpenKey","HKCR","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Maximum Allowed, Granted Access: All Access"
"cmd.exe","RegQueryKey","HKCR","SUCCESS","Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0"
"cmd.exe","RegOpenKey","HKCR\.vbsd","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Delete"
"cmd.exe","RegDeleteKey","HKCR\.vbsd","SUCCESS",""
"cmd.exe","RegCloseKey","HKCR\.vbsd","SUCCESS",""
"cmd.exe","RegQueryKey","HKLM","SUCCESS","Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0"
"cmd.exe","RegOpenKey","HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Query Value"
"cmd.exe","RegQueryValue","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\GlobalAssocChangedCounter","SUCCESS","Type: REG_DWORD, Length: 4, Data: 108"
"cmd.exe","RegCloseKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer","SUCCESS",""
"cmd.exe","RegQueryKey","HKLM","SUCCESS","Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0"
"cmd.exe","RegCreateKey","HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Set Value, Disposition: REG_OPENED_EXISTING_KEY"
"cmd.exe","RegSetValue","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\GlobalAssocChangedCounter","SUCCESS","Type: REG_DWORD, Length: 4, Data: 109"
"cmd.exe","RegCloseKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer","SUCCESS",""
"cmd.exe","RegCloseKey","HKCR","SUCCESS",""
```

And unsuccessful `assoc .vbsd=` with unexpected `The system cannot find the file specified` message:

```
"Process Name","Operation","Path","Result","Detail"
"cmd.exe","RegQueryKey","HKLM","SUCCESS","Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0"
"cmd.exe","RegOpenKey","HKCR","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Maximum Allowed, Granted Access: All Access"
"cmd.exe","RegQueryKey","HKCR","SUCCESS","Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0"
"cmd.exe","RegOpenKey","HKCR\.vbsd","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Delete"
"cmd.exe","RegDeleteKey","HKCR\.vbsd","CANNOT DELETE",""
"cmd.exe","RegCloseKey","HKCR\.vbsd","SUCCESS",""
"cmd.exe","RegQueryKey","HKCR","SUCCESS","Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0"
"cmd.exe","RegOpenKey","HKCR\.vbsd","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Maximum Allowed, Granted Access: All Access"
"cmd.exe","RegDeleteValue","HKCR\.vbsd\(Default)","NAME NOT FOUND",""
"cmd.exe","RegCloseKey","HKCR\.vbsd","SUCCESS",""
"cmd.exe","RegCloseKey","HKCR","SUCCESS",""
```

Unfortunately, I can't discover where subkeys under `HKCR\.vbsc` come from in your case.

**added note from barlop**  --- As to where it came from, I think it was a combination of 'default programs editor' and start/orb.."change the file type associated with a specific extension" and making a .vbsc icon and choosing a program with open with, and assoc ----